# PHP e MySqli. Problema na ligação à tabela

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados, conexão, mysqli

Estou a seguir um toturial, está tudo igualzinho. O meu problema é que não consigo ligar-me à tabela.

connect.php:

```
<?php

    $db = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'user', 'pass', 'app');

    if ($db -> connect_errno) {
        die ('Sorry, we are having some problems.');
    }

?>
```

Este funciona corretamente, a ligação à DB é feita sem probs.

O problema está aqui:

index.php

```
<?php
    require_once('db/connect.php');

    $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM people") or die ($db->error);

    if ($result->num_rows) {
        echo 'yay';
    }
?>
```

O query dá esta mensagem de erro sendo esta:

> Table 'app.people' doesn't exist

Sendo que, só `people` é o nome da tabela

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: No seu php no lugar de `select ... people` mude para `show tables` e veja se vai aparecer a tabela `people`. Na dúvida tente recriar ela.

Comment: "yay", creio que seja bom sinal.... Apesar de não perceber o que se passa neste caso

Comment: vc precisa  de um forech em `$result` ou um `print_r()` para ver o resultado da consulta.

Comment: Miguel, mas afinal chega no "yay" ou não?

Comment: Sim, com 'show tables' chegou.

Comment: 'print_r($result)' = "mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 ) ".... está errado

Comment: Pode ser problema de permissão, tentou acessar com o usuário root do seu mysql?

Comment: Também já tinha pensado nisso, mas creio que não... A permissão está do lado www-data (linux)

Answer (score 1):

A sintaxe de conexão é:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("meu_host", "meu_usuário", "minha_senha", "meu_banco");
```

Portanto no seu caso, o erro está informando que não existe a tabela `people` no banco de dados `app`, certifique-se que exista em seu banco `app` esta tabela. **[Veja mais...](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysqli-connect.php)**

Comment: Muito obrigado, mas a tabela existe sim

Answer (score 1):

Desse jeito funcionou para mim:

connect.php

```
<?php
// Mantenha o @, ele esconde o echo automatico do erro
$mysqli = @new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "user", "pass", "app");

/* checar conexão */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Erro ao contectar:: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

index.php

```
<?php
require_once('db/connect.php');

/* Executar query */
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM people");

/* Checar se a query teve sucesso */
if (!$result) {
    printf("Erro ao executar query: %s\n", $db->error);
}

/* Pegar o numero de linhas */
$rows=mysqli_num_rows($result);

/* Checar se o numero de linhas selecionadas é maior que 0 */
if ($rows>0) {
    echo 'Yay';
}
```

Se ainda não funcionar cheque as permissões da db ou tente num server online...